# Geometry nodes instances follow curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a belt system where I can instance objects and move them on a closed curve.
Only I made it this far, I can instance objects randomly on a curve but not with an equal distance. I have managed to make one instance follow a curve but not multiple.
I have seen some tutorials but people seem to have trouble with it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with this node setup you can change your speed and the number of instances:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure wish this answer wasn't outdated by new Blender updates. I wonder what I could change to make it work for the most recent version.

Comment: Just ask a new question. I am sure you will get an answer soon. But sorry, I will not and i cannot update my thousands of answers here.

Comment: i just looked at the nodes...r u sure this doesn't work anymore!?